# How to suppress autocomplete for email address in Gmail without deleting from Contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-auto-complete

I have contacts who have changed email address over the years. I don't want to lose my record of their old addresses in case I want to read old emails. But I want to remember which email to use when drafting a new email. I already have the old address labeled as "old address" but this is insufficient.

Is there a way for Gmail not to suggest an old email address in Autocomplete?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't turn off auto-complete for some addresses -- it's either all or none. However, as a workaround, you can move the old email address from the "Email" field in the contact record to the "Notes" field.

[image]

Using this workaround, you can still save the old email address for reference, and it will still come up in search results (in both Gmail and Contacts) but Gmail's auto-complete won't try to insert it when you compose an email.

To move an old email address from the "Email" field to the "Notes" field:

1. Go to your [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/)
2. Browse or search your list of contacts for the contact you want to change
3. Click on the pencil icon ("Edit contact") to the right of the contact (it will appear when you hover over the contact)
4. Cut the email address from the "Email" field
5. Paste it into the "Notes" field
6. Click Save

Comment: That is a great workaround. Thanks.